# Pod is not able to connect to internet

Tags: kubernetes

Pod hosted on K8s cluster is not able to connect to the internet:

```
[root@master micro-services]# kubectl exec -it webapp-77896f4bf8-8ptbb  -- ping google.com
ping: bad address 'google.com'
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the name servers by opening `resolv.conf` in your container's directory:

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

You can test by adding Google's public name server like:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Should resolve internet issue by adding above line to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

A better way is to use Kubernetes's own core DNS as described [here](https://blog.yaakov.online/kubernetes-getting-pods-to-talk-to-the-internet/).

Comment: If someone wants to read the documentation, follow this link:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-dns-cluster/